# Matrix of ranking

Tags: graph-theory, matrices

In any graph of n nodes in any dimension, define matrix $M_r$ of ranking as $\forall r_{ij}\in M_r$, $r_{ij}$ is the ranking of j to i. That is, j is the $r_{ij}$th nearest node to i. Therefore, any row in $M_r$ is a permutation of {1,2,...,n} if we assume no ties, and $r_{ii}=1,\forall i$.

I wonder whether there are any more properties of this kind of matrix. For example, is all kinds of permutation possible? Thanks a lot!